# How do I get the SID number from whoami /all in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I tried  `whoami /all | Select-String -Pattern 'SID'` but it only gets the 'SID' string instead of it's value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which one of the SIDs of `whoami /all` do you want?

Comment: Do you need only your users SID or those of all groups? Do you want to use the output in powershell or just print it? Try `whoami /user`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `whoami`is that it is simply returning an array of lines which you then have to analyze yourself. Are you bound to use `whoami`? There are more convenient ways to find your SID. For example:

```
(New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($env:username)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).value
```

If you have to use `whoami`, this is working for me... but it might fail once the output is not as expected:

```
$data = whoami /all
foreach ($line in $data){
    if ($line -match "SID"){ #search for the first occurence of "SID"
        [int]$index = $data.indexof($line) + 2 #skip title + delimiter
        break
    }
}
write-host "username: $($data[$index].split(' ')[0])"
write-host "SID: $($data[$index].split(' ')[1])"
```

Answer (score 1):

To parse all users and groups from the output of `whoami /all` the code below should work.
It returns an array of `[PsCustomObjects]` with properties `Name`, `SID` and `Type` (either 'User' or 'Group').
This alows you to save it as CSV file if you want.

```
$type  = ''
$result = (whoami /all) | ForEach-Object {
    switch -Regex ($_) {
        '^User\s?Name'  { $type  = 'User' ; break }
        '^Group\s?Name' { $type  = 'Group'; break }      
        '^\s*$'         { $type  = '' ; break}
        '^=+'           { $width = $_ -split ' ' ; break }
        default {
            if ($type -eq 'User') {
                $sidStart = $width[0].Length + 1
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    'Name' = $_.Substring(0, $width[0].Length).Trim()
                    'SID'  = $_.Substring($sidStart, $width[1].Length).Trim()
                    'Type' = $type
                }  
            }
            elseif ($type -eq 'Group') { 
                $sidStart = $width[0].Length + $width[1].Length + 2
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    'Name' = $_.Substring(0, $width[0].Length).Trim()
                    'SID'  = $_.Substring($sidStart, $width[2].Length).Trim()
                    'Type' = $type
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'UsersAndSids.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Update**

The `whoami` also has a switch `/FO CSV` with which the output is in CSV format with empty lines between the user and groups data. Unfortunately, this output too is localized.
Using calculated properties however, it is possible to return the property names in English.

The code for that approach, for convenience in a function:

```
function Parse-WhoAmI {
    $nl = [Environment]::NewLine
    # join the array with newlines and split into two blocks on the empty line
    # the first block contains User info; the second block is for the groups
    $data = ((whoami /ALL /FO CSV) -join $nl) -split "$nl$nl" | Select-Object -First 2

    # output the user data with English column names
    $userdata  = $data[0] | ConvertFrom-Csv
    $headers   = $userdata[0].PSObject.Properties.Name  # get the localized header names
    $userdata | Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = { $_.$($headers[0]) }}, 
                              @{Name = 'SID'; Expression  = { $_.$($headers[1]) }},
                              @{Name = 'Type'; Expression = { 'User' }}


    # do the same for the Groups block
    $groupdata = $data[1] | ConvertFrom-Csv
    $headers = $groupdata[0].PSObject.Properties.Name
    $groupdata | Select-Object @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = { $_.$($headers[0]) }}, 
                               @{Name = 'SID'; Expression  = { $_.$($headers[2]) }}, 
                               @{Name = 'Type'; Expression = { 'Group' }}
}

# call the function
$result = Parse-WhoAmI

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'UsersAndSids.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

More wmi options:

```
get-ciminstance win32_useraccount | select name,sid

get-ciminstance win32_userprofile | select localpath,sid

get-localuser | select name,sid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wmi to do this:

```
Get-WMIobject -Query "Select SID From Win32_UserAccount" | Foreach {Write-Host $_.SID}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups.Value
```